# Print character in a Linux shell by id using printf

Tags: bash, shell

I'm missing some characters in my keyboard, so I'd like to know how to print a character in the Bash shell using the ASCII character id.
For example, the character '{' has the ASCII code 123.
Using C's like syntax I've tried with:

```
printf("%c\n", 123);
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"%c\n",'
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The correct syntax in the shell is `printf "%c\n" 123` but it just prints `1`

Comment: `printf "\x$(printf %x 123)"`

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need ALT+NumPad key input? Anyway, on an Italian keyboard the brakets are ALTGR+SHIFT+[ ALTGR+SHIFT+]

Comment: `echo 123 | awk '{printf "%c\n", $1}'`